# Translate CoreLocation Coordinates onto a PDF map

Tags: ios, pdf, core-location

I have a to-scale PDF representation of an outdoor facility. I want to show the user where they are on the PDF while allowing the user to zoom/pan/scale the PDF. Much like what is done in the Six Flags Theme Park App.

What frameworks/API are recommend for accomplishing this?

[image: Six Flags Park Map]

Comment: You have a relative 2D space with known size and lat-long position. You can thus convert a actual lat/long point to a point on your picture with a bit of rectangle math.

Comment: Very short: MapKit, image of the park and MKOverlayRenderer - https://www.raywenderlich.com/9956648-mapkit-tutorial-overlay-views